# Force transitive persistence order in JPA 2 w/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, cascade

Is there any way to force the persistence order of objects in JPA 2 w/Hibernate?

Say I have three classes: `Parent`, `Child`, and `Desk`.  `Parent` owns collections of `Child` and `Desk` via `@OneToMany`; a `Child` can have one `Desk`.  Furthermore, `Parent` defines transitive persistence on both collections, but `Child` does not define transitive persistence on its `Desk`:

```
class Parent {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) Collection<Child> children;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) Collection<Desk> desks;
    ...
}

class Child {
    @OneToOne(cascade={}) Desk desk;
    @ManyToOne Parent parent;
}

class Desk {
    @ManyToOne Parent parent;
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to create a Desk and a Child at the same time and persist the relationships:

```
Parent parent = em.find(...);
Child child = new Child();
Desk desk = new Desk();
// add both desk and child to parent collections here
// set Parent attribute on both desk and child
```

If I execute the above code in a transaction, Hibernate cascades from `Parent` to its new `Child` and attempts to persist the new `Child` object.  Unfortunately, this results in an "object references an unsaved transient instance" error, because the cascade from `Parent` to `Desk` hasn't resulted in the new `Desk` object being persisted yet.

I know I can fix the problem with an EntityManager flush() operation (`em.flush()`) - create the `Child`, create the `Desk`, attach both to `Parent`, `em.flush()`, then attach the `Desk` to `Child`, but I'm not super-keen on littering my code with `em.flush()` to save complex graphs of new persistent objects.  Is there a different way to signal to JPA 2 or Hibernate that it should always persist the new `Desk` first instead of the new `Child`?

Comment: Why is your "OneToOne" cascade type empty? shouldn't it be at least "PERSIST"? And also, how do you know that hibernate cascades from Paren to Child? maybe Desk fails because it is trying to be cascaded from Parent unsuccessfully, instead of from Child.

Comment: The lifetime of the `Desk` object is determined by the lifetime of the `Parent` object, but not the `Child` object - so `Parent.desks` has `CascadeType.ALL`, whereas `Child.desk` has no cascade.

I have unit tests that confirm the cascade from `Parent` to its collection of `Desk` objects and from `Parent` to its collection of `Child` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your description, I think that the Persistence system tries to persist first in this order:

- First the Parent.children[i]
- Each Children[i] has a transient pointer to Desk. The system fails to persist it because you have not configured it as Cascade.Persist.

Then it fails when persisting Desk, and you think that it fails in the path Parent.desks[i] (which is configured as Cascade) but maybe the fail doesn't come from this path.

Comment: Adding CascadeType.PERSIST to Child.desk *does* achieve the desired behavior.  I'm not necessarily keen on that option, but it's better than littering my code with em.flush().